# sql quest with amount and exchange rate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to choose customers who have made a large amount of payments in December 2018 if we take into account the exchange rate

I have a table:

- Trandate date - transaction date
- Transum numeric (20,2) - amount of payment
- CurrencyRate numeric (20,2) - currency exchange rate

```
 ID_Client  Trandate    Transum CurrencyRate    Currency
 --------------------------------------------------------
 1          2018.12.01  100     1               UAH
 1          2018.12.02  150     2               USD
 2          2018.12.01  200     1               UAH
 3          2018.12.01  250     3               EUR
 3          2018.12.02  300     1               UAH
 3          2018.12.03  350     2               USD
 7          2019.01.08  600     1               UAH
```

but I think that "max" is not at all what I need

```
 SELECT ID_Client, MAX(Transum*CurrencyRate) 
 FROM `Payment.TotalPayments` 
 WHERE YEAR(Trandate) = 2018
       AND MONTH(Trandate) = 12
```

I need something this

```
ID_Client   Transum 
   3         1750
```

Where 1750 is a "UAH" and 350USD + 300UAH + 250EUR, exchange rate of USD is 2, exchange rate of EUR is 3.

Comment: From your sample data, what is the expected output? Can you please add it.

Comment: okay, and how take this into exchange rate ?

Comment: ID_CLIENT  - 3    Transum  - 1000UAH

where transum = 300uah+350usd

Comment: Why `250EUR` i.e., `250*3` is not included for `ID_Client 3` in the expected output? It means each client's top 2 highest Transum only consider for the calculation?

Comment: sorry corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the sum of transaction amounts by client for the year 2018 and month of December, you could write it like this:

```
SELECT ID_Client, SUM(Transum*CurrencyRate) as payment_total_converted
FROM `Payment.TotalPayments` 
WHERE YEAR(Trandate) = 2018
and MONTH(Trandate) = 12
group by ID_Client
```

If you want things grouped by each client, year, and month in a given date range, you'd write it like this:

```
SELECT ID_Client, YEAR(Trandate) as tran_year, MONTH(Trandate) as tran_month, 
SUM(Transum*CurrencyRate) as payment_total_converted
FROM `Payment.TotalPayments` 
WHERE Trandate between '2018-12-01' and '2019-01-01'
group by ID_Client, YEAR(Trandate), MONTH(Trandate)
```

I added a column name for your computed column so that the result set is still relational (columns need distinct names).

I'd recommend reading up on the SQL 'group by' clause (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and aggregate (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) operators.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `sum()`.  Then you can `order by` the result:

```
SELECT ID_Client, SUM(Transum*CurrencyRate) as total 
FROM `Payment.TotalPayments` 
WHERE Trandate >= '2018-12-01' AND Transdate < '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY ID_Client
ORDER BY total DESC;
```